# Transpile ES6 nested node_modules dependency of the top level node_modules dependency

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, node-modules

I have a dependency in my **node_modules** in ES6 format and it has its nested node_modules dependency is the ES6 format as well.

I managed how to include the top level dependency eg **dependencyA** into the babel config and transpile it as the project code as well. But how to do it if this dependency has other dependencies in the ES6 format?
So: how to configure babel/webpack to transpile the nested **node_modules** dependency?

Here is the structure

```
Project (Babel/Webpack/Typescript)
 - node_modules
   - dependencyA (ES6) // ok, added top level ES6 dep to babel transpilation
     - node_modules
       - nested_dependency (ES6) // what to do with that?
```

Should I go deeper and manually include such a nested node_modules package as well?

eg. *babel.config.js*

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    sourceMaps: true,

    include: [
      path.resolve('src'),
      path.resolve('node_modules/dependencyA'), // ok, added top level ES6 dep

      path.resolve('node_modules/dependencyA/node_modules/nested_dependency'), // should I do that?
    ],
    presets: [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      '@babel/preset-react',
      '@babel/preset-flow',
      '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ],
  .....
```

it looks a bit redundant. Is there exist a way to handle it?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is cool way to do this using regex negative look a head.

> The syntax is: `X(?!Y)`, it means "search X, but only if not followed by Y".

Let's say that you know which node_modules deps (on the first level) you want to transpile.

You can specify this regex `/(dep1|dep2)[\\/](?!.*node_modules)/`.

```js
const PATH_DELIMITER = '[\\\\/]'; // match 2 antislashes or one slash
const safePath = (module) => module.split('/').join(PATH_DELIMITER);

const generateIncludes = (modules) => {
  return [
    new RegExp(`(${modules.map(safePath).join('|')})$`),
    new RegExp(`(${modules.map(safePath).join('|')})${PATH_DELIMITER}(?!.*node_modules)`)
  ];
};

const generateExcludes = (modules) => {
  return [
    new RegExp(
      `node_modules${PATH_DELIMITER}(?!(${modules.map(safePath).join('|')})(${PATH_DELIMITER}|$)(?!.*node_modules))`
    )
  ];
};
```

This code is taken from [next-transpile-modules](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules/blob/master/src/next-transpile-modules.js).

This 2 functions should be called with an array of modules that you need to transpile, and pass it to `include` & `exclude`

Comment: Hi, felixmosh. Thank you for your answer. It looks like it's a correct solution and it could work even in the case of nesting but, to be honest, it's too complicated for me =)
I just ejected all dependencies and put them into my project because I didn't manage how to parse them, unfortunately.